# How to deploy / host Tableau Extension

Tags: tableau-api, github-pages, web-hosting

I have built a Tableau extension, and now need to publish the extension in a manner that (a) allows others in my organization to view dashboards using the extension + utilize the extension in their own dashboards, and (b) does (a) in a secure manner.

This page of the Tableau Extensions API docs (https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/docs/trex_contributing.html#hosting) suggests two approaches for hosting extensions:

1. Host your static content on GitHub pages
2. Host your node app on Heroku

Regarding these approaches, I don't believe (1) is sufficiently secure, as (my understanding is that) GitHub Pages are publicly accessible by all, whereas (2) seems a bit excessive.

I am wondering if there is a way to host on GitHub pages, but also make the extension / web app accessible **only** to users with access to the private repository. Otherwise, I am seeking other possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: Hey Canovice, is there a server within your organization that you can host the extension? For authentication, you can use something like https://simplesamlphp.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how dynamic your extensions are, you can simplify deployment with AWS S3 or similar. I've used S3 bucket hosting for all of my extensions to this point with no problems. That should meet both your privacy and availability requirements.